# SonarQube dockerfile on Azure App Service Linux Container: Error Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start

Tags: sonarqube, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy sonarqube image 8.7.0 using dockerfile via azure pipelines on Azure Web Service for Linux containers. I have deployed the app service infrastructure (such as App service plan, Azure SQL Database) with ARM template. whenever I deploy the Sonarqube dockerfile, I always get the error:  Container sonarqubece87_0_fbe29a39 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start.

I have exposed port 8080 in the dockerfile and websites_port in appsetting of azure app service. also I have exposed port 2222 in the dockerfile as well so that I can open WebSSH.

I have tried many different options (including SSH support in dockerfile) to resolve this HTTP pings on port 8080 error but nothing is working.

Can someone guide me please to resolve this.
Thank you

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile and the steps you follow to deploy the app service?

Comment: Try to read [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196997/azure-deployment-failure-container-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-on-port-8080#comment117079792_66196997) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212658/react-app-not-loading-with-docker-compose/66213919#66213919), if it useful to you, pls let me know.

Comment: @JasonPan I tried to use your post1 but still same error.

Comment: @Anil Pls share your dockerfile as Charles said.

Comment: JasonPan I tried to use your post1 but still same error. Dockerfile link and associated files (such as run.sh, init.sh etc) are here @CharlesXu: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pgUF4oGXxPhsPSPDXOb1b4vmm18Jh7To?usp=sharing

Comment: There are two errors in your Dockerfile, one is you do not expose port 2222 in the Dockerfile, and the second is the `ENTRYPOINT` can only exist one. If there are multiple, the last one will be executed and another will be ignored.

Comment: I have also attached Azure App Service settings screnshort on the above google drive link

Comment: @CharlesXu: I did expose port 2222 in my dockerfile but still did not work however, let me try CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT (CMD ["bin/sonar.sh"])

Comment: @CharlesXu, it did not work again same error

Comment: Do you check if the image can work fine locally?

Comment: Why do you try to ping port 8080? Sonarqube listens on port 9000.

Comment: @CharlesXu, can you please guide me how to check the image work fine locally. sorry I am new to this

Comment: You can take a look at Docker, I mean you can run the image in your local docker server to check if it can work well.

Comment: @JasonPan, do you know how to execute two .sh files in either EntryPoint or CMD in dockerfile. I wan to execute two files (Init_container.sh, sonar.sh) here in dockerfile. what is the best way to do this? Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64895608/run-post-deployment-action-on-azure-app-service/64905246#64905246

Comment: You maybe can exec .sh file by this way.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error now for snoarqube: I am using Azure SQL Server: Web server startup failed
2021-02-25T10:08:22.063660344Z java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database.

Comment: Finally I am able to connect with Azure SQL Server with Sonarqube via Azure Webapp container service however, I am still unable to do SSH into azure webapp container. Do I need to generate keys for the container as well in order to start sshd

Comment: Finally, it is working as I am able to connect to Azure SQL Server and can do WebSSH on Azure Web App Containers for Sonarqube Image.