# Container Port Issue Azure Web App as Container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, containers

I am using following dockerhub image to setup sonarqube on azure web app as Containers.
https://hub.docker.com/layers/sonarqube/library/sonarqube/community/images/sha256-
ae28b0e22676abc26256d7eb1360207fb6ca871db3cb46cb73bfe4f9ed804a8b?context=explore

However, I am having trouble getting webapp to start up.In the logs I have an error.

```
Container  didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 9000, failing site 
start. See container logs for debugging.
```

The image does Expose port 9000

As per MSDN Documentation, I have tried setting Application setting
WEBSITES_PORT=9000

The same issue still persists.

Can anyone point to the reason here ? Does azure web app support dockerhub images which expose another port than 80 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the approach of having the same port you map in docker.

1. Expose port number ‘used by the application’ in Dockerfile
2. Add 2 new values in application settings,

**`Port:9000`**
**`WEBSITES_PORT:9000`**

Comment: do you mean, adding this in azure application settings ?

Comment: yeah under web app

Comment: nope it doesn't work

Comment: have you exposed that port in the docker file?

Comment: it's a public docker file you can see in above link https://hub.docker.com/layers/sonarqube/library/sonarqube/community/images/sha256-ae28b0e22676abc26256d7eb1360207fb6ca871db3cb46cb73bfe4f9ed804a8b?context=explore

Comment: this comment thread may help which has link to answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270320/sonarqube-dockerfile-on-azure-app-service-linux-container-error-container-didn

Comment: turns out i was using a buggy dockerhub image :(